# Hide old attachments from wp media library

Tags: php, functions, media, media-library, wp-editor

I am trying to limit the files that are shown in the wordpress media library popup (from wp_editor).

*Currently every single file that I have ever uploaded to my site is shown in the library but I would like to limit what users see to just files uploaded in the last 24 hours.*

It is possible to limit the media library by author using the following code; however I'm not even sure where to start to limit the media library popup to files uploaded in the last 24 hours.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','users_own_attachments');
function users_own_attachments( $wp_query_obj ) {

global $current_user, $pagenow;

if( !is_a( $current_user, 'WP_User') )
    return;

if( !in_array( $pagenow, array( 'upload.php', 'admin-ajax.php' ) )
    return;

if( !current_user_can('delete_pages') )
    $wp_query_obj->set('author', $current_user->ID );

return;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can adjust the *attachment query* in the media library popup, through the `ajax_query_attachments_args` filter.

Here are two PHP 5.4+ examples:

**Example #1:**

Show only attachments that where uploaded during the last 24 hours:

```
/**
 * Media Library popup 
 * - Only display attachments uploaded during the last 24 hours:
 */
add_filter( 'ajax_query_attachments_args', function( $args )
{
   $args['date_query'] = [['after' => '24 hours ago', 'inclusive' => true ]];
   return $args;
} );
```

**Example #2:**

Show only attachments that where uploaded during the last 24 hours by the current user:

```
/**
 * Media Library popup
 *    - Only display attachments uploaded during the last 24 hours by the current user:
 */
add_filter( 'ajax_query_attachments_args', function( $args )
{
   $args['author']     = get_current_user_id();
   $args['date_query'] = [['after' => '24 hours ago', 'inclusive' => true ]];
   return $args;
} );
```

Comment: This will ony work for the *grid* layout, **it will not work on the *list* layout** of the media library. See this answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/271592/22510

Comment: Thanks for your comment @ThatBrazilianGuy, yes that's true but it looks like OP was only looking for a way to modify the ajax  query request here (not the list layout). I checked the great answer you linked to (by Dave Romsey), and I've already upvoted it in the past ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Add the filter "ajax_query_attachments_args" in this way and URLs variables are sent to the class WP_Query

the default is to send

```
array(7) {
  ["orderby"]=>         string(4) "date"
  ["order"]=>           string(4) "DESC"
  ["posts_per_page"]=>  string(2) "40"
  ["paged"]=>           string(1) "1"
  ["post_type"]=>       string(10) "attachment"
  ["post_status"]=>     string(15) "inherit,private"
}
```

Here you can modify to your liking

```
add_filter( 'ajax_query_attachments_args', 'my_ajax_query_attachments_args', 1, 10 );

function my_ajax_query_attachments_args($query) {
  $query['date_query'] = array(
    array(
      'before'     => "-1 day",
      'inclusive' => true,
    ),
  );
  var_dump($query);
  return $query;
}
```

Comment: I think your `priority` and `arguments` are in the wrong order in your `add_filter`, and you might want to remove that `var_dump()` from the filter function too.