# Restrict WordPress Media Library for a specific user role (users can only see/select own media)

Tags: uploads, media, media-library, dashboard

I have 4 roles in my platform : administrator, author, editor, external

I need to restrict WordPress media library access to the user’s own uploads only for one users role (**external**) on my platform.  **The External user role can only see/select his own media**.

All others roles still have access to all medias in the library.

I found the below snippets but it works for all the users :

```
<?php // Limit access to media library (users can only see/select own media) //
   add_filter( 'ajax_query_attachments_args', 'wpsnippet_show_current_user_attachments' );
   function wpsnippet_show_current_user_attachments( $query ) {
      $user_id = get_current_user_id();
      if ( $user_id && !current_user_can('activate_plugins') && !current_user_can('edit_others_posts')) {
         $query['author'] = $user_id;
      }
      return $query;
   }
?>
```

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: I'd go with just another upload folder for external users. Catch the user role on login, distinguish upload folder by a filter based on that.

Comment: Is it possible to show me how to do this please ?

Comment: Here's an answer that addresses the list-view version: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/271584/can-i-hide-the-attachments-from-media-which-i-uploaded-from-front-end/271592#271592

Answer (score 0):

add this to your functions.php or in a snippet, with this code the users with role external will only see their own uploads, any other role will see them all just has before.

```php
add_filter( 'ajax_query_attachments_args', 'role_external' );
function role_external( $query ) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    if ( $user_id && current_user_can('external') ) {
        $query['author'] = $user_id;
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: This will still show all images to people who use the list view, and if you can guess the edit URL they'll still be accessible as well.

Comment: in my dashboard this works like a charm, however I didnt take in account the direct link to the images, that way probably they will still have access, about the list view, dont know it.

Comment: I can confirm that the solution above only works in grid mode. List mode shows all media files.

Answer (score 0):

to protect your image folder try use this

Add a simple .htaccess file in your site folder with the following lines

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www\.your-domain\.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www\.your-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(wav|swf|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|js|css)$ - [F,NC,L]
```

Note I added also js and css file even if I think it's bizzare to find someone who attempts to scrape them.

this answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990337/how-to-protect-against-direct-access-to-images)